# How to return a blank line in ISim?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, xilinx-ise

What it currently looks like in my Console Window:

```
at 20 ns: Note: TimerCount: 0 (/TEST_tb/).
at 20 ns: Note: TimerTriggerSync: '0' (/TEST_tb/).
at 22500 ps: Note: TimerCount: 2 (/TEST_tb/).
at 22500 ps: Note: TimerTriggerSync: '0' (/TEST_tb/).
at 25 ns: Note: TimerCount: 2 (/TEST_tb/).
at 25 ns: Note: TimerTriggerSync: '0' (/TEST_tb/).
at 27500 ps: Note: TimerCount: 2 (/TEST_tb/).
at 27500 ps: Note: TimerTriggerSync: '0' (/TEST_tb/).
at 30 ns: Note: TimerCount: 2 (/TEST_tb/).
at 30 ns: Note: TimerTriggerSync: '0' (/TEST_tb/).
```

What I'd like it to look like:

```
at 20 ns: Note: TimerCount: 0 (/TEST_tb/).
at 20 ns: Note: TimerTriggerSync: '0' (/TEST_tb/).

at 22500 ps: Note: TimerCount: 2 (/TEST_tb/).
at 22500 ps: Note: TimerTriggerSync: '0' (/TEST_tb/).

at 25 ns: Note: TimerCount: 2 (/TEST_tb/).
at 25 ns: Note: TimerTriggerSync: '0' (/TEST_tb/).

at 27500 ps: Note: TimerCount: 2 (/TEST_tb/).
at 27500 ps: Note: TimerTriggerSync: '0' (/TEST_tb/).

at 30 ns: Note: TimerCount: 2 (/TEST_tb/).
at 30 ns: Note: TimerTriggerSync: '0' (/TEST_tb/).
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

**EDIT:**

This code

```
    report "Bad Test";
    report "TimerTrigger: " & std_logic'image(TimerTrigger);
    report "TimerTriggerSync: " & std_logic'image(TimerTriggerSync) & LF;
```

prints out this:

```
at 25 ns: Note: Bad Test (/TEST_tb/).
at 25 ns: Note: TimerTrigger: '1' (/TEST_tb/).
at 25 ns: Note: TimerTriggerSync: '0'
 (/TEST_tb/).
at 40 ns: Note: Bad Test (/TEST_tb/).
at 40 ns: Note: TimerTrigger: '1' (/TEST_tb/).
at 40 ns: Note: TimerTriggerSync: '0'
 (/TEST_tb/).
at 55 ns: Note: Bad Test (/TEST_tb/).
at 55 ns: Note: TimerTrigger: '1' (/TEST_tb/).
at 55 ns: Note: TimerTriggerSync: '0'
 (/TEST_tb/).
at 70 ns: Note: Bad Test (/TEST_tb/).
at 70 ns: Note: TimerTrigger: '1' (/TEST_tb/).
at 70 ns: Note: TimerTriggerSync: '0'
 (/TEST_tb/).
```

This would work perfectly if I didn't have to print out the file name (/TEST_tb/) as well.  This is the new obstacle to work around.

Comment: Is this a VHDL question? You added a Virtual-Hard-Disk (VHD) tag to your question. Also your Question does not state which is the destination language. You can not add empty lines to a log, because each logline represents one message. But you could add newline characters. A STRING in VHDL is a CHARACTER array. CHARACTER is an enum and defines several control chars like LF or CR. You can simply concatenate these chars into strings. `report "Line 1" & CR & "Line 2" severity NOTE;`.

Comment: Another solution is to write to STD_OUT, but there is no correlation to a time in simulation unless you use `now()` in your message.

Comment: yep, sorry!  And I'm referring to the Console Window in ISim right before the TCL command prompt where "assert" and "report" statements appear.  But there's no way to return just a blank message?

Comment: A blank message like `report "" severity NOTE;` would also create a line: `at 30 ns: Note: (/TEST_tb/).`. It's a short line, but no blank line. Maybe you can use a very long line for separation: `report "----------------------------------------------" severity NOTE;`

Comment: Without seeing any code, what provides the order of those two messages? If their order is guaranteed append a LF or CR (or both what ever causes a newline in your implementation) to the second message. That will insert an empty line following the second message. Show us one or both report statements.

Answer (score 3):

In your report statement, you can try:

```
Report "My Stuff" & LF severity NOTE;
```

If that does not do it, add the following after your TimerTriggerSync reports:

```
use std.textio.all ; 
. . . 
write(Buf, string'(""));
writeline(OUTPUT, BUF);
```

You might also try the following after your TimerTriggerSync reports:

```
write(std.textio.OUTPUT, "" & LF);
```

Comment: I edited my above code to show what your first example gives me.  Very close to what we'd like to get, but it returns the file name.  Also, when I try to use your "write" examples, I'm getting this error:  ERROR:HDLCompiler:69  Line 124: <write> is not declared.  Do I need to include a new library declaration to allow this?

Comment: Yes.  You need the package I added above.  Generally you will put it before the entity declaration.  In the last example, if you only print once, you can reference OUTPUT as std.textio.OUTPUT.